# How to call function in ionic angularjs with local notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application that has two buttons , Add button and Schedule button , 
When i click on the add button the notification will be triggered then the notification tab will appeared .

Here is the code

Js code

```js
app.controller('contNoti', function ($scope, $cordovaLocalNotification)
{
    $scope.add = function () {
        var alarmTime = new Date();
        alarmTime.setMinutes(alarmTime.getMinutes() + 1);
        $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
            id: "1234",
            date: alarmTime,
            message: "This is a message",
            title: "This is a title",
            autoCancel: true,
            sound: null
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("The notification has been set");
        });
    };

    $scope.isScheduled = function () {
        $cordovaLocalNotification.isScheduled("1234").then(function (isScheduled) {
            alert("Notification 1234 Scheduled: " + isScheduled);
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<ion-content ng-controller="contNoti">
    <button class="button" ng-click="add()">Add notification</button>
    <button class="button" ng-click="isScheduled()">Is Scheduled</button>
</ion-content>
```

Ok, what I need is to make the same application with the same functionality but without the buttons. I want it to be executed automatically without clicking on the buttons. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you want to run `$scope.add()` no matter what, is that correct?

If so, just add `$scope.add();` after the `$scope.isScheduled = function () {...};` block.

I hope that's the answer you're looking for, otherwise, please provide more details.

Comment: thanks ,  i am sorry because my bad english , i couldn't explain my problem .. 

back again , 
there is 
$scope.add= function(){..}
im my code the add button calls this function ..

Comment: i want the add function be called when i open thee app .. i tried your way and i get this error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined

Comment: I used 
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {}

i added the function inside it , and everything works now .. 

do you have any idea , what it's work with     $ionicPlatform

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger your methods with the events from $ionicView:

Inside your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(data) {
     $scope.add();
     $scope.isScheduled();
})
```

They will be executed once the User enter to the view.

Note: Those functions could be private(not attached to the $scope). Because they wont be used in the View.

Comment: Does it work? Make sure you add this to your Main controller.

Comment: i have only one controller in my page called " contNoti "  , i added your code to it .. but it doesn't work

Comment: Remove the event, and just execute the functions once the controller is loaded. Did you try that? Just add $scope.add();
     $scope.isScheduled(); after you define the functions.

Comment: Yes i tried it , and i got this error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined

Comment: Take into account that when you use any of those $cordova plugins, you are using native functionality of the phone. So you must be sure that the $ionicPlatform is ready. Otherwise you will receive an error.